# trouble in loop in R: matrix or data frame in the beginning?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame (new_t) with rows=strains (28 of them) and columns are genes (12559 of them) and the cells are the expression values for these genes. i want to see the correlation of each gene with the last one. so i want to compare each column like a vector to the last column vector..

```
> rr<-matrix()
> for (i in 1:ncol(new_t)) {
  bb<-cor(x=new_t[,i], method='spearman', y=new_t[,12559])
  rr<-cbind(rr, bb)
  }
```

my problem is that when the loop finishes, rr that is formed is all composed of bb's.. as in bb bb bb bb...

if i change rr into a data frame, it gives me error

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
 arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` to avoid the `for` loop and get the same resutls.

A toy example

```
> set.seed(1)
> new_t <- matrix(rnorm(100, 100, 3), 10)
> apply(new_t, 2, cor, method="spearman", y=new_t[,10])
 [1] -0.30909091 -0.17575758  0.41818182 -0.36969697 -0.33333333  0.10303030 -0.18787879 -0.36969697
 [9]  0.01818182  1.00000000
```

I think that with your data it should be:

```
apply(new_t, 2, cor, method="spearman", y=new_t[,12559])
```

Or even simplier using just `cor` without `apply` and selecting the last column from the correlation matrix.

```
> cor(new_t, method="spearman")[, ncol(new_t)]
 [1] -0.30909091 -0.17575758  0.41818182 -0.36969697 -0.33333333  0.10303030 -0.18787879 -0.36969697
 [9]  0.01818182  1.00000000
```

Comment: thank you i used the apply function and solved the problem. thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

From the help page of `cbind` (`?cbind`):

> If there are several matrix arguments, they must all have the same
>   number of columns (or rows) and this will be the number of columns (or
>   rows) of the result. If all the arguments are vectors, the number of
>   columns (rows) in the result is equal to the length of the longest
>   vector. Values in shorter arguments are recycled to achieve this
>   length (with a warning if they are recycled only fractionally).
>
> When the arguments consist of a mix of matrices and vectors the number
>   of columns (rows) of the result is determined by the number of columns
>   (rows) of the matrix arguments. Any vectors have their values recycled
>   or subsetted to achieve this length.
>
> ...
>
> The `cbind` data frame method is just a wrapper for `data.frame(...,
>   check.names = FALSE)`. This means that it will split matrix columns in
>   data frame arguments, and convert character columns to factors unless
>   `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is specified.

I suspect that you are mixing up the number of rows. I'm not sure why you are getting your error with `matrix()`, as you did not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/). Applying `cbind` to `data.frame()` throws an error because the number of rows do not match.

```
## this seems to work
cbind(matrix(),cor(1:10,2:11))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   NA    1

## this throws an error
cbind(data.frame(),1)
# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

You'd be better off avoiding the for-loop altogether and using `apply` or `sapply`:

```
sapply(seq_len(ncol(new_t)), function(i) 
  cor(x=new_t[,i], method='spearman', y=new_t[,12559]))
```